# Java code example to make video call in facebook

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

Is there any code available in java where i can connect to FB account make video call from my application sending some parameters like user to be called and all..

does RestFB or GraphFB have something like that?

Comment: words used are java code example facebook api to make video call

Comment: @AndrewThompson ....:) sometime people are too eager to get it.

Comment: We already did 'share some link'.  You seem to be ignoring it. :(

Comment: @AndrewThompson, you said it....it will be good idea  to have an animated GIF for this rather than explanation.some kind of special mark up tag may help....:)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses skype infrastructure to make video calls. So they have not exposed any API to make that video calls yet.

This [link](http://www.itproportal.com/2011/07/09/facebook-video-calling-skypes-doing-all-hard-work/) will give you an idea how it works.

Here is a [link](http://skype.sourceforge.jp/index.php?Skype%20API%20For%20Java%20%28English%29) to skype API for Java. See if these helps.